# Change to Address Component Types in India not reflected by Androids Geocoder

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

Because of the [notice about changes to Address Types and Address Component Types for addresses in India](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258777366?pli=1) I was wondering how we can reflect that, using the [Android Geocoder from SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) which returns `Address` objects.
These `Address` objects only return admin area levels 1-2, but not 3, nor 4.

Hence the above mentioned change notice, I need to get the district level admin area, but
I will get the division instead.

**An example:**

This location in Delhi has **North West Delhi** as district (admin level 3).

[developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder?hl=en#q%3D28.704059%252C77.10249)

[image]

But from Androids `Geocoder` for the same lat/lon I get as first `Address` only level 1 and 2.

```
Address[addressLines=[0:"delhi green park 16 delhi green park 16, Lodhi Colony, Sector 3, Rohini, Delhi, 110085, India"],feature=Lodhi Colony,admin=Delhi,sub-admin=Delhi Division,locality=Delhi,thoroughfare=null,postalCode=110085,countryCode=IN,countryName=India,hasLatitude=true,latitude=28.7040517,hasLongitude=true,longitude=77.1024532,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]
```

See `admin=Delhi,sub-admin=Delhi Division,locality=Delhi,`

Is it even possible to get admin area level 3 from `Geocoder`?
Will there possibly be an update in the future to reflect the changes on API side?

Comment: You should ask Google directly via their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188871).

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290079307

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the [Android Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) is **not** one of the [Google Maps Platform Services](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-services). Its functionality is much more limited than that of the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding) which is the one you would need to use in order to obtain additional address components.

Comment: Yes, I know that the Geocoder in the SDK is limited and does not provide the same detailed results. But at the moment it returns different administration levels, depending on the location. And that seems to be an unwanted behaviour to my understanding.